# blank pdf files at S3 when uploading with Serverless framework API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, serverless-framework

I am uploading pdf file to S3 with this function via postman/multipart file upload.

```
  public async upload(folder: string, fileName: string, content: any, language: string): Promise<void> {
   try {
     const bucketParams = {
       Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
       Key: common.buildObjectKey(folder, fileName, language),
       Body: Buffer.from(content),
  };

  await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams));
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Upload failed. Error: ", error);
 }
}
```

content argument comes from my Lambda function event which is multipart file

```
const multipart = require("aws-lambda-multipart-parser");

export const handler: Handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const { folder, fileName, language } = event.pathParameters;
    const parsedEvent = multipart.parse(event, true);
    ....
```

When I run this code from Serverless Offline i.e. locally, it works, however, the deployed code at AWS doesn't work. here are the file size differences.

[image]

at serverless.yml I have as it's described here at [aws-lambda-multipart-parser npm package page](https://github.com/myshenin/aws-lambda-multipart-parser)

```
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - 'multipart/form-data'
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. sending a file with post request via form data in the body is also called multipart/form-data since the file is being sent in parts. Sorry for any confusion but those 2 terms are used in parallel.

Comment: you can check this resource out: https://moduscreate.com/blog/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-a-serverless-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and had to add the following:

```
apigwBinary:
types:
  - 'multipart/form-data'
  - 'application/pdf'
```

Comment: did you use also another library/plugin for receiving and assembling the file?

Comment: Yes I used: lambda-multipart-parser
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-multipart-parser